# What is the programming paradigm of Dtrace?

Tags: paradigms, dtrace

I've been using Dtrace for a while, and as time goes by I've began to wonder what's the programming paradigm of the D language used in Dtrace.

It's not an imperative language, I guess, so that means it's some sort of declarative  functional language, but I'm no expert in language taxonomy, so what should the D language  officially (or semi-officially) be classified as?

Answer (score 2):

The D language seems to be a subset of C with added builtins (variables, functions) specific to tracing. It can be compared to awk or YACC programs in structure: it consist of a list of one or more instrumentation points (probes, rules), and each probe is associated with an action.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Dtrace is obviously related to [aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), in that it somehow  *weaves* its probes into the programs under study.

I would say that the specification of the weaving points belongs to the *declarative programming* world, while the probes themselves are programmed imperatively (C-like). Not sure is this answers your question though :-)